# Confusing settings and behavioure for my User Profile service inside my on-premises sharepoint farm 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, self-service

I am working on a sharepoint enterprise farm on-premises. and inside the farm i find these settings regarding the **User Profile Service** which have been set previously by our customer.

- central administration >> application management >> select the web application>> self-service site creation. i find these settings:-

[image]

- central administration >> managed services >> User Profile >> My site. i find these settings:-

[image]

- central administration >> managed services >> User Profile. i find that there are 25 user profiles.

[image]

- when i view all the site collections. i can find only 4 site collections for the personal sites.

[image]

now the confusion i am getting are as follow:-

1. i can count around 20++ users which have their personal sites created. because  when i click on a user name inside the sites, i will be redirected to such a site, and this is the case for at-least 20 users:-

[image]

but when i checked the site collections , i can only find that there are 4 personal site collections (as shown above)?? so what is the reason. i was assuming that i should get 20 personal site collections, not only 4?

2. when i manually navigate to one of the personal site url by typing the following "`http://XXX/my/personal/user_abc`" i will be redirected to the following url "`/my/Person.aspx?accountname=`" ?? so what does this mean? now the URL for the mysite site collection should be something such as "`/my/personal/..`" and not "/my/person.aspx?accountname" ??
3. inside the web application's self-service site creation, what does "Be Hidden from users" for "start a site" mean ? and if i am hiding this from users,, then how the 4 site collections have been created?? could this setting be changed after the 4 site collections have been created.?
4. final question . now out customer have around 120 users. so will there be any drawbacks if the 120 users created there own my-sites?? could this slow the sharepoint ? or it is a matter of storage ?? not a matter of server RAM consumption?

can anyone adivce on my above 4 points please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What you are seeing, is profile page (Person.aspx?accountname=??) of the user, where u will get information about users. U are seeing 4 sites because 4 users created their mysite so far. if you browser the site which u are seeing from central admin then you will get the shared document library page.
2. Again, only 4 people created the mysites, ask other user to click on the onedrive link which will provision their mysite.
3. This link will allow user a create team site on the URL which u masked(red ink). If u enable it, u will see a create a site on your mysitehost url. Be hidden will hide it from enduser. which is mostly company doing.
4. I dont see any pressure on the farm with 120 mysites, Mysite are very light weight, may be storage will be an issue but not the performance.

Comment: thanks for the reply... now for point 2. now inside the central admin>>view all site collections. i can see that there is a site collection with the following url `/my/personal/user_a` , but when i navigate to this site i will be redirected to the following url `/my/Person.aspx?accountname=` .. i mean i am talking about navigating to a mysite based on the url mentioned inside the CA>>view all site collections. but seems i will be redirected to this url `/my/Person.aspx?accountname=`. for point number 3. now inside the current setting we have the option set to "hide from end users"

Comment: but what i did , i login using a test account (nameduserABC), then under the username on the upper hand side of the screen, i click on about me link, i was redirected to this url `/my/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Person.aspx?accountname=companyA\userABC`, tehn i click on the user image, then i checked the "CA>>view all site collections"... and i can see that a new site collection `/my/personal/userABC` has been created.. so seems even with the option set to "be hidden from users", users are able to create mysites..  is this correct?